# Diplay interface Prometheus

Tags: istio

I have a problem.
When I execute the command
`kubectl port-forward -n monitoring prometheus-prometheus-operator-prometheus-0 9090`
 on my cluster Kubernetes (AKS) it gives me this result

```
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1.19090 -> 9090
Forwarding from [:: 1]: 9090 -> 9090
```

and when I put the URL http://127.0.0.1:9090/targets on my browser, I have no result.

```
 $ kubectl get pods -n monitoring
NAME READY STATUS RESTARTS AGE
alertmanager-prometheus-operator-alertmanager-0 2/2 Running 0 11h
prometheus-operator-grafana-8549568bc7-zntgz 2/2 Running 0 11h
prometheus-operator-kube-state-metrics-5fc876d8f6-v5zh7 1/1 Running 0 11h
prometheus-operator-operator-75d88ccc6-t4lt5 1/1 Running 0 11h
prometheus-operator-prometheus-node-export-zqk7t 1/1 Running 0 11h
prometheus-prometheus-operator-prometheus-0 3/3 Running 1 11h
```

What should be done ? or how to forwarding prometheus from my public cloud to my local machine.
Thank you

Comment: "I have no result" > what is "no result"? Some HTTP error? Blank page? Timeout?

Comment: as @Joel asked, please elaborate your "no result", also I recognized on your output, this shows `Forwarding from 127.0.0.1.19090 -> 9090` and why **19090**? Either you did typo on your output or it can be cause to look for your failure?

Comment: It is a mistake, Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:9090 -> 9090
Forwarding from [:: 1]: 9090 -> 9090   I can not redirect it from my AKS to my localhost: 9090

Comment: please explain then what is happening when you go to `localhost:9090` in browser?